# Protocol-buffer with Python choose the order of data with SerializeToString

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, protocol-buffers, protoc

I have buffer that encoded with protocol-buffer , I want to read the buffer and change some data and encode it again.

I saw that when I encode the buffer ( `SerializeToString`) the binary data is not the same so the server that get that buffer can't decoded that .

```
import messages_pb2
with open('proto.bin','rb') as f:
    buffer1 = f.read()
my_obj1 = messages_pb2.MyObj()
my_obj1.ParseFromString(buffer1)
buffer2 = my_obj1.SerializeToString()
```

When I look at the binary data I think that the order of the data is changed. Is there any way to `SerializeToString` but the choose the order of data ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned in the Protocol Buffer documentation:

> When a message is serialized, there is no guaranteed order for how its known or unknown fields will be written.

However, this shouldn't be a problem if you are using Protocol Buffers to deserialize the data. If you have a custom parsing algorithm that parses that data, then you might want to either refine the algorithm to not care about the order, or use Protocol Buffers.

As I don't have much more information here, please let me know how I can better help.